# Trailer Category Naming in SQL Query without changing Source Table Information

Tags: sql

I am writing a basic SQL query and want to group certain trailer numbers into categories that are non-existent in the source table. For Example, trailers 12345, 45678, and 98765 (in the Trailer field) should be 'Stretch Trailers'. Thanks for the help.

I assume the below is incorrect because it is failing.

```
AND Trailer in ('123456', '45678','98765') = 'Stretch'
```

Comment: Use a `case expression`.... such as `select case when trailer in (1,2,3) then 'Stretch' else t_name end as trailer from table where...`

Comment: Please supply some proper tabular sample data desired results and the DBMS

Comment: To address the comment you just deleted... Then select the column twice.... `select trailer, case when trailer in (1,2,3) then 'Stretch' else trailer end as trailer_group from table...`

Comment: Do you store numbers as char/varchar?

Comment: @Isolated I assume this would work for multiple categories? Thank you for your help                                                                      Select CASE when Trailer in (1,2,3) then "Stretch", when Trailer in (4,5,6) then "Flatbed" else "Trailer"

Comment: Yes, see answer below. Do not put commas between your `when` conditions.

Comment: Please learn SQL syntax.  You can't write whatever syntax you want, and expect your program to understand what you want.

Comment: Learn to ask question here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  If you post question with the necessary information, then maybe people can help you.  Posting a quarter of a query will not help people help you.

Comment: I was helped… I can’t post company sensitive information and just needed to know to group categories which could and was accomplished using CASE which was new to me. I got the syntax wrong initially as you noted. Not sure how publishing an entire query would have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `case expression` for this type of result.

```
select
 trailer, 
 case 
  when trailer in ('123456', '45678','98765') then 'Stretch'
  when trailer in ('444', '4566') then 'Low'
  when trailer in ('999999') then 'High Step'
  else 'Other'
 end trailer_group, 
 col3, 
 col4
from table 
where ...
```

Comment: Should this suffice as your answer, then please considering marking the Accept flag.